# ActionScript3 - Mario like obstacle

Tags: actionscript-3

Want to create a mario like obstacle.

if mario hits it from left then i want to stop increasing x pos of mario and if it hits from right then the y pos. Also if mario stand over it then it should not keep dropping.

How can I check using hittesy (or by any other method) that whether it has touched from left, right or above.

Comment: Have you got a HitTest function that isnt working as expected? In general detecting the obstacle works like in this tutorial: [Link](http://asgamer.com/2009/as3-flash-games-for-beginners-registering-hit-tests) where the green "hitarea" square shown would on the characters body. You detect if that is touching the obstacle. It will be a starting point for you but you can also fine tune this by moving onto the bitmap collision detection shown further down. Hope it helps

Comment: PS: Use `if` statements inside an `enterFrame` event to do whatever when character hits obstacle. When your HitTest is true you can check if the character X pos is smaller than half your stage size. Example formula `(if hitTest is true) { if (char.x < screen half) { //assume hit on left side of screen and do required} else {//assume hit right side and do required}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep track of the player's PREVIOUS position (ie, its position in the previous frame). From the player's position previous to the impact frame you can tell from which direction it impacted the object; From the left, right or above.